# What does pcpu signify and why multiply by 1000?

Tags: linux, process, cpu, cpu-usage, ps

I was reading about calculating the cpu usage of a process.

```
seconds = utime / Hertz

total_time = utime + stime

IF include_dead_children
     total_time = total_time + cutime + cstime
ENDIF

seconds = uptime - starttime / Hertz

pcpu = (total_time * 1000 / Hertz) / seconds

print: "%CPU" pcpu / 10 "." pcpu % 10
```

What I don't get is, by 'seconds' the algorithm means the time computer spent doing operations other than the interested process, and before it. Since, uptime is the time our computer spent being operational and starttime means the time our [interested] process started.

Then why are we dividing the `total_time` by `seconds` [Time computer spent doing something else] to get `pcpu`? It doesn't make sense.

The standard meanings of the variables:

```
 #  Name      Description
14  utime     CPU time spent in user code, measured in jiffies
15  stime     CPU time spent in kernel code, measured in jiffies
16  cutime    CPU time spent in user code, including time from children
17  cstime    CPU time spent in kernel code, including time from children 
22  starttime Time when the process started, measured in jiffies

/proc/uptime :The uptime of the system (seconds), and the amount of time spent in idle process (seconds).

Hertz        :Number of clock ticks per second
```

Comment: Given that we have no idea how/where/to what `utime`, `Hertz`, `stime`, `cutime`, `cstime`, `uptime`, `starttime`, etc. are defined, any attempt to answer this would have to make a fair number of assumptions. It would be better if you could elaborate on what all your variables are and what values they contain (or where they come from, at least)...

Comment: These are standard terms. But, then, I will update the question for your sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've provided what each of the variables represent, here's some comments on the pseudo-code:

```
seconds = utime / Hertz
```

The above line is pointless, as the new value of `seconds` is never used before it's overwritten a few lines later.

```
total_time = utime + stime
```

Total running time (user + system) of the process, in jiffies, since both `utime` and `stime` are.

```
IF include_dead_children
     total_time = total_time + cutime + cstime
ENDIF
```

This should probably just say `total_time = cutime + cstime`, since the definitions seem to indicate that, e.g. `cutime` already includes `utime`, plus the time spent by children in user mode. So, as written, this overstates the value by including the contribution from this process twice. Or, the definition is wrong... Regardless, the `total_time` is still in jiffies.

```
seconds = uptime - starttime / Hertz
```

`uptime` is already in seconds; `starttime / Hertz` converts `starttime` from jiffies to seconds, so `seconds` becomes essentially "the time in seconds since this process was started".

```
pcpu = (total_time * 1000 / Hertz) / seconds
```

`total_time` is still in jiffies, so `total_time / Hertz` converts that to seconds, which is the number of CPU seconds consumed by the process. That divided by `seconds` would give the scaled CPU-usage percentage since process start if it were a floating point operation. Since it isn't, it's scaled by 1000 to give a resolution of 1/10%. The scaling is forced to be done early by the use of parentheses, to preserve accuracy.

```
print: "%CPU" pcpu / 10 "." pcpu % 10
```

And this undoes the scaling, by finding the dividend and the remainder when dividing `pcpu` by 10, and printing those values in a format that looks like a floating point value.

Comment: So, can we say that `pcpu` is the percent of the 'age' of our process that the process actually utilizes CPU?

Comment: Yes. It's not an "instantaneous" CPU usage percentage like you'd get from `top` or such (which isn't really instantaneous anyway, there's still a short interval over which it's measured), but a percentage based on total CPU usage vs total running wall-clock time for the process.